# Query to show the product categories that contains more than 1 product with price higher than 10

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a SQL Query to show the product categories that contains more than 1 product with price higher than 10

The table "Product" of a database contains the columns

```
NAME VARCHAR2(256) NOT NULL, 
CATEGORIE VARCHAR2(64) NOT NULL 
PRICE NUMBER(9,2) NOT NULL
```

Follow this example of database:

```
NAME    CATEGORIE   PRICE 
BREAD   BAKERY       3.00 
CHEESE  BAKERY      25.00 
MEAT    BUTCHERY    23.00
PORK    BUTCHERY    41.00
SOAP    CLEANING    15.00
```

In this case, the query will return only "BUTCHERY" because it's the only categorie that contains more than 1 product with the price higher than 10.

Comment: Do you mean with a `PRICE > 10`? as there is no `value` column

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Only the categorie that contains more than one product with the price > 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CATEGORIE
from Product
where price > 10
group by CATEGORIE
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result set is empty. The result should be just "Butchery".

Comment: what result do this query `select count(*) from Product where price > 10` ?

Comment: the result is 4

Comment: sorry! I made a mistake in the request. I've fixed it now.
take the updated query. in query i group by name? but need by categorie

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's done. Really appreciate it